# Why am I getting all uppercase requests in cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-cloudfront

I am hosting binary executables in cloudfront. I link to said executables on a webpage. Normally the path is /path/exe_name/exe_name.exe. When I look at CloudFront Popular Objects Report the biggest 4XX I have is /PATH/EXE_NAME/EXE_NAME.EXE which is the exact name except entirely uppercased. This also only happens to the windows executable, I have no entries of this occurring for mac executable. QE and dev have not been able to reproduce this issue. Why does this happen? Is there any way to fix this other than uploading the file in all caps case?

Comment: CloudFront does not transform any HTML, can you validate the request from the origin (take CloudFront out of the picture).

Comment: s3 is the backing source, do you think hitting s3 directly would provide more information?

Comment: Yes, try accessing the content in S3 and validate

Comment: Note, months later we've never resolved we just upload in lower and upport case now...